# Increase efficiency with VBA loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm brand new to this site. I've got no coding skills but I decided to tackle Excel VBA because I want to make my work flow more automated. Here is my problem. I made my macro out of stuff I dug out of the web(sorry I cant add proper credit to the creator). It consolidates information from 40 files. These 40 files have the same basic layout but different info. What I need to do is copy several different ranges to a single worksheet. I've got it working but I'm pretty certain its done the hard way.

[My worksheet I pull data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j4Q1.jpg)

What I currently do is copy cell A1 to my consolidate sheet with a loop which opens each of the 40 files and closes them. Then I copy cells A17:G23 to the consolidate sheet with a loop which opens each of the 40 files and closes them. Then I copy cells D5:G11 to the consolidate sheet with a loop which opens each of the 40 files and closes them.

Basically I open each file a total of 7 or 8 times with loops. Now I've taken down my work time down from 2 hours to ~3 minutes. But I think this isnt quite as efficient as it could be. Should I try to fix it or should I leave it be since it works?

All the loops look like this one with just different target cells to copy and paste. Thank you in advance.

```
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim LastRow As Long

'This is the path to the files
Path = "D:\work\"  'Change this path
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

'Opens the files
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'If the next file exists then
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

'Below this is the code I use to edit each file

'Copies from the work files
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
 If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
 ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
 End If
 LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 Range("a2:aa2").Select
 Selection.Copy

 Windows("example.xlsx").Activate


 'Chooses the tab from the consolidation file and copies the data there
 Sheets("test").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 :=False, Transpose:=False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Do you only care about the values of the cells or do you also need to copy the formatting?

Comment: You will save a fair bit of time and effort if you drop the `Select` and `Activate` commands from your code as they're not necessary if you fully qualify the workbook and worksheets.  For example you could use `Set wSheet = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")` and have no need to `Select` it.  Similarly use `Range("a2:aa2").Copy` instead of `select`ing it and then using `Selection.copy`.  Since the code is working, you might find it better to post it to codereview.stackexchange.com which is the site for discussing improvements in efficiency in working code

Comment: @Mono I only care about values.

Comment: @Dave I will give it a shot. Also I will redirect my question to codereview.

Thank you.

Comment: Then throw away all the Select and copy stuff and you will only need one Loop for everything. You can do it like @Dave suggest. Reference the worksheet you need and then do something like this wSheetTarget.Range("A1:AA1).value = wSheet.Range("A1:AA1").value

Comment: I might not have explained it properly. Since each work file has 11 sheets I had to hardcode the select sheet because I dont want to have to make sure that everytime i close one of the work files its on the proper tab. Also replacing the `selection.copy` with `range.copy` works nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off a huge thank you to @Dave, @Mono and @MutjayLee for the help. They pointed me in the direction I needed. I found a better way of doing the loops and here is the whole macro I use. It now runs only 1 loop instead of 8. And runtime has been lowered from ~2 minutes to ~30 seconds. Which is what I wanted.

If someone thinks this can be made better, please share with us. I would love to make this even better.

I removed the parts of the code that were just formatting since those were just recorded within excel and were WAY too long.

```
Sub Consolidate_ALL()

'Created on: 11.05.2016
'by Shakdun
'Change Log:
'Date - Change made
'06.06.2016 - Added new formulas to cells A2, B2 and H2 in tab "Sheet2" that are added to each file.
'06.06.2016 - Added macro optimization. DisplayAlerts.
'08.06.2016 - Changed some comments.
'09.06.2016 - Changed the way the macro selects the source sheets and the way it copies the data from them.
'10.06.2016 - Added macro optimization. Calculation.
'15.06.2016 - Changed the way LOOPs work. Now instead of 7 or 8 loops it only has 1. Meaning it wont open each file 8 times, but only once. It copies all the information and then it makes adjustments outside of the loop. Speed increase! Run time: ~32 seconds. (run time before this update: ~2 minutes)
'16.06.2016 - Changed some comments. Changed the filtration of example2. Reviewed the code and removed redundant parts.
'16.06.2016 - Changed some formating that kept switching between the sheets several times. Now it just switches once and all formating is done a sheet at a time.
'End Of Change Log   

'Macro optimization
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Windows("example.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("test").Select
    Range("A2").Select

'Declare and set variables
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

'Path to source files
Path = "D:\work\"  'Change path here
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls") 'file format has to be the same as source files

'Start of loop. This opens the source files
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    Set wSheet = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set wSheets = wbk.Worksheets("LNum")
    Set wSheet1 = wbk.Worksheets("PS")

'This is what copies the data
wSheet.Range("a2:aa2").Copy
Windows("example.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("test").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

wSheet.Range("a3:aa3").Copy
Windows("example.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

wSheets.Range("C6,C7,C17").Copy
Windows("example.xlsx").Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

wSheets.Range("C1").Copy
Windows("example2.xlsm").Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

wSheet.Range("C14:D14").Copy
Windows("example2.xlsm").Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

wSheet1.Range("D5:F11").Copy
Windows("example2.xlsm").Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(7, 0).Select

wSheet1.Range("A17:G23").Copy
Windows("example2.xlsm").Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(7, 0).Select

     wbk.Close True
     Filename = Dir

Loop

Windows("example.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("test").Select

'this creates a new first column and fills it with 1, 2, 3 patern
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A7").FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A2:A7.Copy
    Range("A8:A649").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("test2").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("test").Select
    Range("A2").Select

'This cuts a specific row and pastes it on sheet test2
endRow = 1000 'probably not the best way to get the last row but it gets the job done
pasteRowIndex = 2

For r = 1 To endRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

    If Cells(r, Columns("A").Column).Value = "2" Then 'Found

            'Cut the current row
            Rows(r).Cut

            'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
            Sheets("test2").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1


           'Switch back to the main sheet & continue to search for your criteria
            Sheets("test").Select
    End If
Next r

'This cuts a specific row and pastes it on sheet test2
endRow = 1000 
pasteRowIndex = 1

For r = 1 To endRow 

    If Cells(r, Columns("A").Column).Value = "3" Then 'Found

            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r).Cut

            'Switch the sheet
            Sheets("test3").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1

            Sheets("test").Select
    End If
Next r

'This deletes empty rows
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A1").Select

'This deletes the first row in all 3 sheets
    Sheets("test").Select
    Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("test2").Select
    Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("test3").Select
    Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

'Random formatting that was recorded

'More random formatting

'Moving data to appropriate places
    Sheets("test3").Select
    Range("A1:C10000").Copy
    Sheets("test2").Select
    Range("B2:D10001").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("test3").Select
    Range("A1:C10000").Copy
    Sheets("test").Select
    Range("B2:D10001").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A2").Select

 'Even more formating

    Windows("example2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Web").Select

    'this creates a new first column and fills it with 2,7 3's and 7 4's like before

'This cuts a specific row and pastes it on sheet test2 like before
'This cuts a specific row and pastes it on sheet test2 again

'This deletes empty rows
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A1").Select

'More formating
'Coloring cells and more formatting. Like several hundred rows of formatting code.

'Removing macro optimization
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding **Select**.

Unless you want to see the actual data copied. but it will be really hard to see because it will be just blink :)

So instead of

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("a2:aa2").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows("example.xlsx").Activate


'Chooses the tab from the consolidation file and copies the data there
Sheets("test").Select
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
 :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Try this

```
with Workbooks("Your source workbook").Sheets("Sheet2")
     If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .AutoFilterMode = False

     LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("a2:aa2").Copy Workbooks("example.xlsx").Sheets("test").Range("A1")
End With
```

By the way, I didn't really get the part ActiveCell.Select.

because that must be target location, but you are selecting the sheets("test") with code.

That means either you have the cells selected on the other code, or it was just recorded macro...I don't know...

I just put Range("A1"), which you can change later

---

In addition, if you have lots of formula, it better to turn off calculation by

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Because excel will try to calculate every formula whenever there is change,

and it will go much faster without calculation untill you are finished.

And at the end of the loop, make sure you add

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

to turn the calculation back on.

---

One more thing I want to add is

Open 40 files beginning of the all loops you mentioned.

and Close 40 files after you are done copying everything, not just once.

Opening 40 files and saving 40 files 7~8 times will take alot longer than just open and close 40 times :)

Comment: So here is the layout. The 40 workfiles each have 11 sheets. Sheet1, Sheet2 etc. The consolidation file has 2 sheets(one consolidates generated info from SQL the other my calculations that confirm the sql stuff). That is why I have hardcoded the sheets in there. And I use the active cell thing so I can offset it by one cell down. Currently I cant run the snippet you gave me @MutjayLee because it pastes everything on the same row. Im still trying to figure out why it doesnt offset it but 1.5 hours have passed and Im no closer to finding out why. Also apart from the loops everything is recorded.

Comment: You used Activecell.Select to get the next row of what you saved last time...is that correct? if that's the case, from **.Range("a2:aa2").Copy Workbooks("example.xlsx").Sheets("test").Range("A1")**, you can change **Range("A1")** to **Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)** This will paste it at the end of data. Did I understand your problem right???

Comment: I think you understood me however this line `.Range("a2:aa2").Copy Workbooks("example.xlsx").Sheets("test").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` throws up an error - `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`. Tried changing a few things(even though ive no clue what im doing) but doesnt seem to want to work.

Comment: Basically the consolidation file has to have information from the source files on a new row for each source file. If i have 40 source files i need 40 rows in the consolidation file that hold info

Comment: What am I thinking...sorry It should be **Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)**

Comment: Awesome! @MutjayLee Works like a charm. Now I just have to apply my Dr Frankenstein powers to make it work with the 6 other loops. Make it all work from within this one. Thanks again :)

Comment: Dang... @ MutjayLee It only works for the one thing. When i tried to apply the same system but a bit modified I mustve screwed it up royaly. What i do is copy a2:aa2 and paste it. WORKS! I copy a3:aa3 and paste it. Doesnt work. Pastes all the formulas and not just the values. Then i try to apply this technique to weird ranges with an offset of 8 cells down and thats when everything went downhill. Data gets copied in the wrong place, gets merged wrongly and erased. I think I shouldnt have tried to fix something that wasnt broken :D

Comment: Copy will make target exactly same as source. if the source is formula, it will copy formula, if the target is colored, it will copy color. If you want to copy only value, you can do **Workbooks("example.xlsx").Sheets("test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("A2:AA2").Value** Instead. This you can change to A3 or A4 or whatever, it will grab the value, and it won't mess up your output

Comment: And what do you mean by offset 8 cells..offset 8 from source? or target?

Comment: I copy 8 cells high and 4 cells wide into a target sheet and I need to offset the target cell by 8 down so it doesn't overlap the data. Also I get an error - error 13 type mismatch. Seems I haven't declared something and is bugging out the macro. Problematic code is the newest snippet. What I'm copying from the source contains only numbers and 2 cells that contain dates. I figure since its all numbers it wont be an issue but it is. I cant figure out what to declare.

Comment: Sorry for double posting. Cant figure out this comments system...
Here is what I'm working with(edited to hide confidential info).
![Source 1](http://i.imgur.com/JuboxoQ.jpg). ![Source 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5j4Q1.jpg). From source 1 I take rows 2(2 goes on sheet1 in consolidation file 1) and 3(3 goes on sheet2 in con file). From source 2 I take A2 and paste it and after that A17:G23 and after that I take D5:F11 and paste it next to the other paste from source2 in con file 2.